# Confusion about hough transformation for ellipse

Tags: hough-transform

I saw the following sentence from [Feature Extraction & Image Processing, 2nd Edition](http://books.google.co.kr/books?id=Td7b0lKum-AC&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=thus+the+mapping+defines+the+trace+of+a+hypersurface+in+a+5d+space&source=bl&ots=lNR6hf2ti4&sig=dZsWAOHIhwlOo18cUgPUNUp3TuU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gBgaUvH-CuawiQfdkoDwBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=thus%20the%20mapping%20defines%20the%20trace%20of%20a%20hypersurface%20in%20a%205d%20space&f=false)

> $$
> x = a_0 + a_x\cos(\theta)+b_x\sin(\theta)
> $$ $$
> y = b_0 + a_y\cos(\theta)+b_y\sin(\theta) $$
>
> This equation corresponds to the polar representation of an ellipse.

I don't know this meaning. If you need extra information, I'll add it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little mis-leading and confusing.

The usual way to describe an ellipse is [using cartesian ($x,y$) coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equations).  [Another way to represent an ellipse is using polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center) ($r,\theta$) (where $r$ is the distance (radius) from the origin, and $\theta$ is the angle.

What the equation is saying is that the *cartesian* coordinates of the ellipse are parameterized by $\theta$ in the two equations. That is, as you change $\theta$ from 0 to $2\pi$, the values for $x$ and $y$ will lie on the ellipse, for constants ($a_0,b_0,a_x,b_x,a_y,b_y$).